# How to find the difference between two nested arrays and keep track of what is updated, deleted or added

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

**Edit** Still trying to solve this issue, help is greatly appreciated. My biggest problem is identifying which type or value has been **updated** because I need to retrieve the related product details as well.

I have an array of objects called **"oldList"** with the following structure.

```
var oldList = [
  {
    productId: "1",
    productName: "Photo Frame",
    Quantity: "20",
    attributes: [
      {
        type: "frame",
        value: "black"
      },
      {
        type: "finish",
        value: "matte"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    productId: "2",
    productName: "Photo Frame",
    Quantity: "50",
    attributes: [
      {
        type: "frame",
        value: "black"
      },
      {
        type: "finish",
        value: "glossy"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    productId: "3",
    productName: "Photo Frame",
    Quantity: "10",
    attributes: [
      {
        type: "frame",
        value: "white"
      },
      {
        type: "finish",
        value: "matte"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    productId: "4",
    productName: "Photo Frame",
    Quantity: "100",
    attributes: [
      {
        type: "frame",
        value: "white"
      },
      {
        type: "finish",
        value: "glossy"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    productId: "5",
    productName: "Photo Frame",
    Quantity: "89",
    attributes: [
      {
        type: "frame",
        value: "wood"
      },
      {
        type: "finish",
        value: "matte"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    productId: "6",
    productName: "Photo Frame",
    Quantity: "10",
    attributes: [
      {
        type: "frame",
        value: "wood"
      },
      {
        type: "finish",
        value: "glossy"
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Next, I have another list called **"UpdatedList"** with the following structure. It is basically an updated copy of the nested attributes arrays. For example, in the attributes array, there were 3 changes:

1. User replaced the value "black" to "gold". Since I know the user is updating the value from "black" to "gold", other properties such as the productId productName, and Quantity that the user had previously entered in the old list should still be retained, since they are just changing the value from the attribute array.
2. User removed the value "wood"
3. User added the value "silver"

Now, I want to find the difference between the oldList and the newList to keep track of what the user has added, deleted or updated. For example, this is the desired result

```
 var mergeList = [
  {
    // Value is updated from black to gold
    productId: "1",
    productName: "Photo Frame",
    Quantity: "20",
    attributes: [
      {
        type: "frame",
        value: "gold"
      },
      {
        type: "finish",
        value: "matte"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    // Value is updated from black to gold
    productId: "2",
    productName: "Photo Frame",
    Quantity: "50",
    attributes: [
      {
        type: "frame",
        value: "gold"
      },
      {
        type: "finish",
        value: "glossy"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    // No changes
    productId: "3",
    productName: "Photo Frame",
    Quantity: "10",
    attributes: [
      {
        type: "frame",
        value: "white"
      },
      {
        type: "finish",
        value: "matte"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    // No changes
    productId: "4",
    productName: "Photo Frame",
    Quantity: "100",
    attributes: [
      {
        type: "frame",
        value: "white"
      },
      {
        type: "finish",
        value: "glossy"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
   // Newly added. No product details such as productId, Quantity and etc
   // for the time being.
    attributes: [
      {
        type: "frame",
        value: "silver"
      },
      {
        type: "finish",
        value: "matte"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
   // Newly added. No product details such as productId, Quantity and etc
   // for the time being.
    attributes: [
      {
        type: "frame",
        value: "silver"
      },
      {
        type: "finish",
        value: "silver"
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

This is my current code. I do not really know how to approach this situation. FYI, the method **differencewith** is from a library called lodash.

```
 // #1 Inspect and compare (oldlist) with newlist
    var difference1 = differencewith(
      oldList,
      newList,
      isequal
    );

    // #2 compare new list with old list
    var difference2 = differencewith(
      newList,
      oldList,
      isequal
    );
```

Comment: please add a wanted result. what should happen, if an item is deleted or added?

Comment: Hi @NinaScholz! Thanks for the reply, I truly appreciate it. The wanted/desired results is from the variable "mergeList". Basically, If an item is deleted, I will delete the item and its related product details such as productId, productName and quantity.

Comment: @NinaScholz If an item is just added, I will just include a new attributes array with the new value. The user will fill in the productId, productName and quantity at a later time.

Comment: HI @NinaScholz, i have added some comments to my code

Comment: If you don't mind using a library, you should check out [DeepDiff](https://github.com/flitbit/diff). Basically does what you're asking for here.

Comment: Hi @ndoes Will look into this library. Is it possible if you can apply this library to my existing code?